# Failed to execute the maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a two maven projects named Test1, and Test2. I have a FirstClass java file in Test1 project and It looks like below:

```
   package com.online.test1;

   public class FirstClass {

      private String test1;

      public String getTest1() {
          return test1;
      }

      public void setTest1(String test1) {
          this.test1 = test1;
      }

    }
```

I have SecondClass java file in Test2 project as shown below:

```
package com.online.test2;

public class SecondClass {

  private String test2;

  public String getTest2() {
      return test2;
  }

  public void setTest2(String test2) {
      this.test2 = test2;
  }

}
```

I just need to call the secondClass java file variables in FirstClass java file, and similar manner I need to call some properties in FirstClass java file in secondClass java file.So, I just added dependencies of Test1 project into Test2 and Test2 project dependencies into Test1 to access the package. But It shows artifact missing error message as shown below in both projects.

*Screenshot:1*

[image]

*Test1 Project POM:*

[image]

*Test2 Project POM:*

[image]

Also the issue will be resolved if I removed Test2 project dependencies from Test1 project and same behavior observed for Test1 project dependencies from Test2 project. But I have a scenario where I need to access the both project class files each other. Don't want to convert the project as jar file and install into local machine.How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You have a cycle in your dependency list - this makes it impossible to decide which project to compile first.

Comment: Do not do circular dependencies.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this task?

Comment: Split classes needed by both modules to a separate shared jar module, or merge Test1 and Test2 into one module. If they're this tightly wound together then it might architecturally not make sense to treat them as separate components. But I can't judge that seeing only a mockup.